# Wrap every element from a list

Tags: prolog, maplist

How do you wrap every element from a list?

I have something like this `(2*3*4*...)^6`

How do I make a list with this output: `2^6 * 3^6 * 4^6 * ...`

I was thinking  on something simple using maplist but I am not sure how to send a parameter to the function in the first argument.

```
simplify(X^Y,R):- X=..[*|Args], maplist(?^Y, Args, Args2), R=..[*|Args2], !.

:- simplify((2*x)^6, (2^6) * (x^6)). %should be true
```

Using Swi-prolog by the way

Comment: Might want to check out [library(yall)](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=yall) which gives you lambda abstractions. Otherwise you'll need to make a predicate to pass into `maplist/3`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your input data structure does not contain any lists, it is a nested structure with numbers at the leaves:

```
?- write_canonical(2*3*4*5).
*(*(*(2, 3), 4), 5)
```

Therefore maplist isn't much use here.  Instead, write a simple recursive predicate to traverse (and reconstruct) the recursive data structure:

```
simplify(N, Exp, N^Exp) :-
    number(N).
simplify(L*R, Exp, LExp*RExp) :-
    simplify(L, Exp, LExp),
    simplify(R, Exp, RExp).
```

The code structure follows the data structure.  Example run

```
?- simplify(2*3*4*5, 6, E).
E = 2^6*3^6*4^6*5^6
Yes (0.00s cpu)
```